# change the post time on multiple posts

Tags: posts, date-time

I have about 60 posts queued and ready to post on specific dates, but I forgot to set the post time. I really don't want a bunch of posts posting at 3AM, so I need to change the times on all these posts.

Is there any way to do this, programmatically or with a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the id of the posts, you can use [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) and change the `post_date`.

```
foreach ($postId as $id) {
  // random hour and time. You can also manually set these.
  $h = rand(1, 23);
  $i = rand(0, 59); 

  $newDate = array(
    'ID' => $id,
    'post_date' => "2013-12-19 $h:$i:59" // [ Y-m-d H:i:s ]
  );

  wp_update_post($newDate);
}
```

Comment: So, I just stick this in a new php file, or where should I stick this?

Cheers